# How to properly format Date in yyyy-mm-dd?

Tags: java, date, java-7

I have a column in my table of Date type in MYSQL and inserting the date format of `25-March-2019 hh:mm:ss` returns an error telling me incorrect data value.

So I have my code written like this:

```
 String startdt=request.getParameter("startdate");
    String enddate=request.getParameter("enddate");
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date Startdate=dateFormat.parse(startdt);
    Date Enddate=dateFormat.parse(enddate);
```

And I am passing `Startdate` and `Enddate` to a function that inserts into my table column.

Is there a way I can have Startdate and Enddate above just return in `yyyy-mm-dd` without the time so I can insert to my db without error?

Comment: Why are you using string formatting at all instead of using a `Date` or `Instant` object directly?

Comment: Because I am getting the value from a html page so it needs to get in string.

Comment: You *really* need to show how you're handling the SQL. This smells like you have injection attacks. (Additionally, while it may be unavoidable in your specific case if you're manually parsing parameters from an `HttpServletRequest` you're Doing It Wrong™, as all major frameworks will do this for you.)

Comment: The time component you see is a relic of how `Date` works internally (it stores a `long` which represents time as an offset from epoch). The new classes in `java.time` work differently, but don't play well with JDBC.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Depends on the JDBC driver. Postgres is okay, but I can't speak for MySQL.

Comment: Why does specifying dateFormat to `yyyy-mm-dd` still returns the time as well?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). You may not need an explicit formatter. And you certainly don’t need to format your `LocalDate` before handing it over to MySQL.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yea `LocalDate` is probably the latest library that most people would suggest but unfortunately,it only works for Java 8 and above.

Comment: Which Java version are you using? `LocalDate` and java.time have been backported, so they work on Java 6 and 7 too. Only unfortunately on those Java versions you will need to convert to the old-fashioned `java.sql.Date` before handing to MySQL. In any case here’s the link to the backport: [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).

Comment: I am using Java 7 though. Heard another commenter mentioned ThreeTen Backport but I unfamiliar with it. What does it actually do? I assume it allows me to use java 8 features backporting it to java 7 version?

Comment: @Daredevil You should have disclosed any constraints, such as being limited to Java 7, in your Question.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
myPreparedStatement
.setObject(
    LocalDate.parse( "2019-01-23" ) 
) ;
```

## `DATE` in MySQL is date-only

The `DATE` type in MySQL is a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone.

Excerpting from [MySQL 8.0 documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html):

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

Use a date-only type in Java for data coming from a date-only type in your database. The `java.util.Date` class you are trying to use is *not* a date, it is a moment in UTC, a date with time-of-day and offset-from-UTC of zero, all tracked as a count of milliseconds from the first moment of 1970 in UTC. The misnaming of that class is only the first of many poor design choices made by those programmers. Move on to *java.time* classes instead. **Stop using `Date`.**

## `MM` = month number, not name

Your format of `"yyyy-MM-dd"` is for a numeric month, not the string of month name shown in your example value of `25-March-2019`.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` classes are terrible, a wretched mess of bad design. They were supplanted years ago with the adoption of JSR 310, implemented in the *java.time* classes.

## Smart objects, not dumb strings

Exchange objects with your database where possible, not text.

As of JDBC 4.2, we can directly exchanged *java.time* objects with the database. For a date-only value, as with SQL-standard `DATE` type, use the `java.time.LocalDate` class.

Apparently, your text inputs for date values is YYYY-MM-DD which is standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 formats by default. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( "2019-01-23" ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , localDate ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
LocalDate localDate = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

> localDate.toString(): 2019-01-23

If you want to produce a string representing the value of that [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html) object in a different textual format, use the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class. Search Stack Overflow for more info as it, like the rest of your Question, has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow. Do search Stack Overflow before posting.

Tip: Generally best to use a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) in your [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) work. One major benefit is thwarting [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) security attacks.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

### Java 7 and ThreeTen Backport

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMMM-uuuu HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String dateFromHtmlForm = "25-March-2019 22:43:55";
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateFromHtmlForm, formatter);
    // We are discarding the time of day and only saving the date
    java.sql.Date dateToSave = DateTimeUtils.toSqlDate(dateTime.toLocalDate());

    String insertSql = "insert into your_table (your_date_column) values (?);";
    try (PreparedStatement insertStatement
            = yourDatabaseConnection.prepareStatement(insertSql)) {
        insertStatement.setDate(1, dateToSave);
        int rowsInserted = insertStatement.executeUpdate();
    }
```

As has already been said, pass date objects to MySQL, not strings. In Java 8 and later these would have been `LocalDate` objects, but in Java 7 we will need to make do with the poorly designed `java.sql.Date` class. It’s still better than strings. And the conversion from `LocalDate` is straightforward.

On Java 7 we can use java.time through the backport, ThreeTen Backport (ThreeTen for JSR-310). My imports are:

```
import org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils;
import org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime;
import org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter;
```

Why would we want to use an external library for this? There are pros and cons, of course. Advantages include:

- java.time is so much nicer to work with than the old-fashoined `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` and gives clearer code.
- It’s future-proof: once you move to Java 8 or later, all you need to do is change your import statements (and discard the library and retest).

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7.
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.